# moving file names to excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

How can I select just the title of a photograph and transfer it to an Excel cell and do a batch of 100 at a time moving each title to the next Excel cell?

Comment: Title? like "PicTitle" from file "PicTitle.jpeg" or the Title property?

Comment: I can do it one by one eg organise, rename,copy then past into Excel BUT I have 500 to do! A batch or via scripts would be easier. Any suggestions or alternative methods?

Comment: Which is it? The actual file names or the property from the image?

Comment: The actual file name only. T

Comment: there are several methods already on the internet e.g. http://smallbusiness.chron.com/copy-list-files-windows-folder-excel-list-40032.html or http://www.thewindowsclub.com/get-list-files-folder-excel

Answer (score 1):

Powershell offers an improved version of the directory listing. This will produce a text listing of your filenames.

This will produce a list of filenames with their path below a location:

```
Get-ChildItem [path] -filter *.jpg -Recurse -Name
```

This will simply list the filenames below a location:

```
Get-ChildItem [path] -filter *.jpg -Recurse | Select-Object Name
```

This list can be imported to Excel.